# iOS dismessed viewcontroller lifecycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller with a button. When you click on a button another viewcontroller is displayed with the method: "presentViewController".

On viewcontroller2 I have an async http-request. When the backend gives an answer to vc2, then I need to update things both on vc2 and vc1. The question is:
If vc2 will be dismissed, will the async-call die?

Comment: Probably not unless it has some mechanism for killing the background thread (or whatever) that's handling the request.  I'd be concerned, though, with how vc2 gets information about the response.

Comment: yes @PhillipMills is write you could use the completion block of the method                                             --(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion to pass the reference of async request or the response back to vc1